# model.predict returns the same values each time

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

```
def main():
    
    
    while True:
        try:
            ret = get_live_data(TICKER)
            print("Live data pre-processing:")
            logging.info(f"Preprocessed data {ret}")
            logging.info(f"Preprocessed data's closing {ret['close']}")
            print(ret)
            
            prepared_data = prepare_data(ret)
            print("Live data post-processing:")
            logging.info(f"Postprocessed data {prepared_data}")
            print(prepared_data)
            predictions = model.predict(prepared_data)
            
            predSecondary = []

            for prediction in predictions.flatten():
                predSecondary.append(prediction)

            #predSecondary = predSecondary[:2]
            print(f"Predictions: {predSecondary}")
            avgPreds = np.mean(predSecondary)
            print(f'Average prediction for current interval {avgPreds}')
model_path = f"informer/{TICKER}{VERSION}/{TICKER}{VERSION}"
try:
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
    tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(0)  # Set learning phase to 0 (inference mode)
except Exception as modelError:
    print(modelError)
scaler_path = f'scalars/{TICKER}{VERSION}.pkl'
if os.path.exists(scaler_path):
    scaler = joblib.load(scaler_path)
    
else:
    raise Exception("Scaler not found. Please ensure that the correct path is provided.")
main()
```

**The problem:**

The prepared_data variable is different from each iteration of the while loop. Yet  each iteration of the while loop returns the same elements for predictions, predSecondary and avgPreds.

**What I've tried to debug:**

I have loaded the model in a seperate script and fed it dummy data, and the prediction was different each time.

**What I need:**

I just want the prediction to not be the same every time in this script.